# How to remove child elements using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have list.

```
<ul id="main">
   <li><a href="#">Blah ...</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Blah ...</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Blah ...</a></li>
   <li id="more">More
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Blah ...</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">........</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">........</a></li>    
       </ul> 
   </li>  
</ul>
```

The main list is displayed to user. When user **hovers** over **list item more**. He sees the dropdown with **more list**. When the user clicks on the **list item** in the **more list**. It should replace **3rd child** in the **main list** and **3rd item** will be added to `#more` list.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

```
#more ul { display: none; }
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#more').hover(function() { $('ul', this).show(); },
                 function() { $('ul', this).hide(); });

$('#more li a').live('click', function() {    
    $(this).before($('#main > li:last-child').prev());
    $('#main > li:last-child').before(this);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/BAJXB/

**EDIT:** I changed `click` to `live` above and removed some unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('#more li').click(function() {
    $('#main li').eq(2).replaceWith(this).appendTo('#more');
});
```

For the hovering, have a look at http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#more').hover(function(){$('#more ul').show();}, function(){$('#more ul').hide();});

$('#more li').click(function(){
    var thirdChild = $('#main li:eq(2)');
    thirdChild.replaceWith(this).appendTo('#more');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R2Fss/4/)

```
$(function(){

$('#more').hover(function(){
    $('#more ul').show();
}, function(){
    $('#more ul').hide();
});

$('#more li').click(function() {
    $('#more ul').append($('#main > li').eq(2))
    $('#more').before(this);
});
```

})